# Affect only the item being clicked, and track unique identifiers?

Tags: javascript, html

So I will have a list of items to check off. They could have the same name/attributes but should all have a unique identifier. I want to be able to check them off of a list and have them run a function on themselves that hides them and send and update to the server with the unique id.

I'm trying to figure out where the unique ID should be stored? Should I use it as a class to easily find the item in the dom? What are my other options for tracking this user input on a particular item? The items will be sent from the server initially.

Here is a start, http://jsfiddle.net/QQPtn/1/ trying to figure out best practices for working with this kind of problem. Thanks!

Comment: isn't the id attribute good choice for uniqueId??

Comment: Yes id would work, when I said class I meant ID, but I don't really want a 64 character id string in my dom for every item. Hoping for a better abstraction on the problem

Comment: I could generate the list from an array of these items and then just use position in the dom to know what the unique item is, maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not wrong there is another option. You can take help of a custom attribute. You can use custom attributes in each image element. Custom attribute can be any user defined name except existing attributes. As an example I can define my own attribute as index="n".

**Example:**

```
 <img src="..." index="1" class="myimage" />
```

On click of the image you can read the attribute index as below

Using normal **JavaScript**

```
var index = element.getAttribute('index');
```

**Using JQuery**

```
 $(".myimage").click(function (s) {
        var imgIndex = s.currentTarget.getAttribute('index');
  });
```